# CloseableAsyncHttpClient not Working for Post MultiPart Request, Response Callback Not Calling

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents, apache-httpasyncclient

I am trying to execute a MultiPart request with form parameters using Apache Async Http Client.

Below is My HttpClientManager,

```
public class AsyncHttpClientManager {

    private final        PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager;
    private static final PropertyFileAccessor                PROPERTY_FILE_ACCESSOR = PropertyFileAccessor.getInstance();
    private static final TaskExecutor                        TASK_EXECUTOR          = TaskExecutor.getInstance();
    private static final Logger                              LOGGER                 = Logger.getLogger(AsyncHttpClientManager.class);
    private static final ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy         KEEP_ALIVE_STRATEGY    = new ConnectionKeepAliveStrategy() {
        @Override
        public long getKeepAliveDuration (HttpResponse httpResponse, HttpContext httpContext) {
            HeaderElementIterator it = new BasicHeaderElementIterator(httpResponse.headerIterator(HTTP.CONN_KEEP_ALIVE));
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                HeaderElement he    = it.nextElement();
                String        param = he.getName();
                String        value = he.getValue();
                if (value != null && "timeout".equalsIgnoreCase(param)) {
                    try {
                        return Long.parseLong(value) * 1000;
                    } catch (NumberFormatException ignore) {
                    }
                }
            }
            return TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(PROPERTY_FILE_ACCESSOR.getIntegerValue("http.connection.keep.alive.seconds", String.valueOf(30)));
        }
    };
    private static final AsyncHttpClientManager              INSTANCE               = new AsyncHttpClientManager();
    private              ConnectingIOReactor                 httpIOReactor;


    private AsyncHttpClientManager () {
        try {
            int timeOut = (int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(PROPERTY_FILE_ACCESSOR.getIntegerValue("http.connection.keep.alive.seconds", String.valueOf(30)));
            IOReactorConfig reactorConfig = IOReactorConfig.custom()
                                                           .setTcpNoDelay(true)
                                                           .setIoThreadCount(200)
                                                           .setSoTimeout(timeOut)
                                                           .setSoReuseAddress(true)
                                                           .setConnectTimeout(timeOut)
                                                           .build();
            httpIOReactor = new DefaultConnectingIOReactor(reactorConfig);
            ((DefaultConnectingIOReactor) httpIOReactor).setExceptionHandler(new IOReactorExceptionHandler() {
                @Override
                public boolean handle (IOException e) {
                    logException(e);
                    return false;
                }


                @Override
                public boolean handle (RuntimeException e) {
                    logException(e);
                    return false;
                }


                private void logException (Exception e) {
                    LOGGER.error("Ion", e);
                }
            });
            HttpAsyncRequestExecutor protocolHandler = new HttpAsyncRequestExecutor();
            final IOEventDispatch    ioEventDispatch = new DefaultHttpClientIODispatch(protocolHandler, ConnectionConfig.DEFAULT);
            TASK_EXECUTOR.executeTask(() -> {
                try {
                    httpIOReactor.execute(ioEventDispatch);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    LOGGER.error("Unable To Instantiate Async HTTP Client", e);
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            });
            connectionManager = new PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager(httpIOReactor);
            connectionManager.setMaxTotal(PROPERTY_FILE_ACCESSOR.getIntegerValue("http.connection.max.count", String.valueOf(10)));
            connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(PROPERTY_FILE_ACCESSOR.getIntegerValue("http.connection.default.per.route", String.valueOf(5)));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Unable To Instantiate Async HTTP Client", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }


    public CloseableHttpAsyncClient getClient () {
        return HttpAsyncClients
                .custom()
                .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                .setKeepAliveStrategy(KEEP_ALIVE_STRATEGY)
                .setConnectionReuseStrategy(new DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy())
                .setConnectionManagerShared(true)
                .build();
    }


    public synchronized void shutDown () throws IOException {
        if (httpIOReactor != null) {
            httpIOReactor.shutdown();
        }
        if (connectionManager != null) {
            connectionManager.shutdown();
        }
    }


    public static AsyncHttpClientManager getInstance () {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

And the Below Part is How Am I trying to call my api,

```
File newsLetter = null;
        try {
            CloseableHttpAsyncClient closeableHttpClient = ASYNC_HTTP_CLIENT_MANAGER.getClient();
            closeableHttpClient.start();
            newsLetter = new File(inputObject.getFileLocation());
            MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
            ...
            multipartEntityBuilder.addBinaryBody("newsletter_file", newsLetter, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY, newsLetter.getName());

            ZeroCopyPost zeroCopyPost = new ZeroCopyPost(url, newsLetter, ContentType.DEFAULT_BINARY) {
                @Override
                protected HttpEntityEnclosingRequest createRequest (URI requestURI, HttpEntity entity) {
                    HttpEntityEnclosingRequest request = super.createRequest(requestURI, entity);
                    request.setEntity(multipartEntityBuilder.build());
                    return request;
                }
            };


            final File finalNewsLetter = newsLetter;

            closeableHttpClient.execute(zeroCopyPost, null, new FutureCallback <HttpResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void completed (HttpResponse httpResponse) {

                    int returnCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                    try {
                        handleResponse(inputObject, finalNewsLetter, httpResponse, returnCode);
                    } catch (ProcessingException | IOException e) {
                        failed(e);
                    }
                }


                @Override
                public void failed (Exception e) {
                    handleError(inputObject, finalNewsLetter, e.getMessage());
                }


                @Override
                public void cancelled () {
                    handleError(inputObject, finalNewsLetter, "Request Cancelled");
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            handleError(inputObject, newsLetter, "FAILED to send email" + e.getMessage());
        }
```

The issue that I am facing with this is whenever I am trying to connect to the api I am getting `SocketTimeoutException` though the api is being able to response to my postman request. If I am missing something please do let me know.

Comment: What is the version of Apache HttpAsyncClient you are using?

Comment: Version that I'm using in this project is `4.1.4`

Comment: What is the version of Apache HttpClient transitive dependency? Make sure it is the latest.

Comment: Everything is Latest

Comment: Post a wire / context log of the session as described here http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/logging.html